# Generators for the intersection of two ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $I=\langle a_1,\dots, a_s\rangle, J=\langle b_1,\dots, b_t\rangle$ be ideals of arbitrary commutative ring.

Then we know that 
$I+J=\langle a_1,\dots, a_s, b_1,\dots, b_t\rangle, IJ=\langle\{a_ib_j \mid 1 \leq i \leq s, 1\leq j \leq t\}\rangle$.

Also $IJ\subseteq I\cap J \subseteq I+J$.

> I wonder about the generators of $I\cap J$. Is it possible that know the generators? Or is it finitely generated?

Comment: In a [GCD domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain) you can define a $\mathrm{lcm}$ in which case $I\cap J = \langle\{\mathrm{lcm}(a_i,b_j)\}\rangle$.

Comment: @JSchlather Your claim is definitely wrong!

Comment: Yes, JSchlather's formula is not correct. $(x,y) \cap (x+y) \neq (x(x+y),y(x+y))$ in $k[x,y]$.

Comment: Exactly as @MartinBrandenburg said, $x+y\in (x,y)\cap(x+y)\backslash(x(x+y),y(x+y)).$

Answer (score 9):

The intersection of any two finitely generated ideals in an integral domain $R$ is also finitely generated if and only if $R$ is [coherent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_ring). An example of GCD domain which is not coherent can be found in Example 4.4 of [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2001-129-10/S0002-9939-00-05882-2/S0002-9939-00-05882-2.pdf). So,

> there are GCD domains which have finitely generated ideals whose intersection is not finitely generated.