# Infinite intersection of finitely generated ideals in a coherent ring.

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, noncommutative-algebra, coherent-rings

It has been claimed without proof in [several](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/295901/354508) [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/669968/354508) that an intersection of two finitely generated ideals in a coherent ring is finitely generated. Thus, the finitely generated ideals in a coherent ring form a lattice. However, can an infinite intersection of finitely generated ideals fail to be finitely generated? The typical examples of coherent rings which are not Noetherian (polynomial ring in infinitely many variables over $\mathbb{Z}$, entire functions on $\mathbb{C}$) seem to have the property that infinite intersections happen to be finitely generated, but for non-general reasons. Does anyone have a nice counterexample?

My motivation is that, given the existence of such a pathological intersection, the abelian category of finitely presented modules can fail to admit certain colimits. Without a reference for the proof of the statement about finite intersections, I don't know where to begin.

[commutative and non-commutative examples accepted]

Comment: As for a reference for the claims in the links, you can go back to the pioneering work of S. U. Chase on coherence, *Direct Products of Modules*.  Theorem 2.2 is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a counterexample.

Let $F_2$ be the field of two elements, and consider the subring of $\prod_{i\in \mathbb N} F_2$ of "eventually constant sequences."

It is commutative and von Neumann regular, so the finitely generated ideals are all principle.  It's coherent because it is semihereditary.

Now, you can take "unit vectors" $e_i$ in this ring, and $1-e_i$ generate a cyclic maximal ideal.

But $\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb N}(1-e_{2i})R$ is an ideal whose elements have to be zero on the "even indices". Therefore every element in it is eventually zero. But clearly it's not generated by a single element, because it contains elements that are nonzero on indices in a cofinal subset of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: An eventually constant sequence which is non-zero only on the odd indices must be zero everywhere, so that intersection is the trivial ideal!

Comment: @MorganRogers What? no. It just has to be zero on the tail.  $e_1$ is in it, for example.  The point is that it has things with support way out there, but no single generator can cover them all (since a generator would necessarily end in zeros at some point.)

Comment: Ah sorry you're right. I've been working with polynomial examples all day, so I flipped some of the bits in my head. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @MorganRogers Thanks for the question. I'm not good with coherent rings, and I'm surprised this example occurred to me.

Comment: @MorganRogers See, in a commutative self-injective von Neumann regular ring, I think the lattice of principal ideals is complete, so it *would* intersect to a principle ideal. But this one is not self-injective.